# Find and replace string with empty paragraph inside .doc and .docx word document

Tags: python, python-3.x, macros, python-docx, find-replace

Sample environment:

```
Dictionary = {"camel":"create-para","donkey":"monkey","cat":"dog"}

cwd = os.getcwd(".")
for files in cwd
    if files.endswith(".doc") or files.endswith(".doc"):
        for Dictionary in files:
            do the changes
```

**2 things to notice:**

- `create-para` in `dictionary` means that remove `string1` and create a new paragraph in place of `string1`.
- In VBA macro it is like this:

  `Dictionary = {"camel":"^p","donkey":"monkey","cat":"dog"}`

However, how to do that?

For example, I want to remove the word materials and replace it with a paragraph

| Before | After |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully sure what you are trying to do here, what is `for Dictionary in files:`? Aren't `Dictionary` and `files` two separate variables? Also, I think your if condition should be:

```
if files.endswith(".doc") or files.endswith(".docx"):
```

If you are trying to change a doc/docx file, you can achieve it using [python-docx](https://pypi.org/project/python-docx/). The [documentation](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) should be able to help you out. If you want to  replace paragraphs, you can use [this snippet](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/30#issuecomment-879593691) from the library's GitHub page. If you want to add paragraphs, you can use the `add_paragraph` function:

```
document.add_paragraph('A plain paragraph having some ')
```

Comment: i am trying to remove a specific string and document.add_paragraph in place of that string

Comment: So then you are trying to replace a paragraph. The GitHub link I posted should help you with that.

Comment: i have thoudsands of words to do with. i cant use your github link. that is only for one word.

Comment: Ok, is calling the method in the loop you already have not an option?

Comment: That is just a sample enivronment. for explanation prupose i used a loop. let it be, let it not be, it does'nt matter